# Kotlin Coroutines wait until done init block

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm currently learning coroutines and need your help :)

How I can force to wait until *retrofit* has initialized?

```
private lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit

init {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        launch {
            val httpClient = createOkHttpClient(...)
            val gson = createGson()
            retrofit = createRetrofit(httpClient.await(), gson.await())}
    }
    logger.debug("Init time: $time")
}

 private fun <T> createService(class: Class<T>) = retrofit.create(_class)
```

With runBlocking it works, but I really not wanted to use this...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> How I can force to wait until my object *retrofit* has initialized?

Coroutines can't help you here. If, before migrating to coroutines, you could afford to block the main UI thread while Retrofit initializes, then leave it like that and don't involve coroutines.

If you had an async task that did it in the background, then whatever the consequences of late init used to be, they will remain with coroutines as well.

The only advantage coroutines give you is the clean programming model:

```
    launch {
        val httpClient = createOkHttpClient(...)
        val gson = createGson()
        retrofit = createRetrofit(httpClient.await(), gson.await())
        ... take the actions that depend on retrofit ...
    }
```

Your coroutine will resume on the UI thread once `httpClient` and `gson` have initialized. It can then take actions that make your app initialization go on. In the meantime the activity's `onCreate` has completed, so you must move whatever stuff you had there that depends on Retrofit into the `launch` block.

Comment: "Your [...] In the meantime the activity's onCreate has completed, so you must move whatever stuff you had there that depends on Retrofit into the launch block."  Sounds like race conditions :( ...
I'm not under an android classes...

Anyway thanks for your hints :)

Comment: Indeed, it means that you can no longer rely on the ordering within a lifecycle callback. Your `retrofit` dependency becomes nullable, you must check it every time. That, or you arrange to start your main activity as a reaction to `retrofit` becoming available.

Comment: Jepp. Thats why I'm asking :) Maybe someone knows an elegant solution. :)